# Just remove a a-zA-z section in regular expression

Tags: php, regex

This is my regex string:

```
'(?!('.$exceptions.')((\W+)|$))[a-zA-Z\-_]+/?$'
```

$exceptions is a variable contains a string like this :

```
word1|word2|word3|word4|wordN
```

I just want to remove the section a-zA-Z which means I want to just delete the rule which checking english chars, because of unicode.

A sample :

```
$exception ='word1|word3|word3|word4' ;
$myword = 'a-unicode-statement-like-سلام' ;
```

If $myword compared with the regex rules string it will not match that because of سلام
it is not in a-zA-z range i just want remove this limitation (a-zA-Z)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Try to provide some input and output examples.

Comment: $string='kjhkjdgdfلبیلبیل%%%^&*('
i want if $string is not equal one of $excpetion words then print true

Comment: [edit] your question.

Comment: I just want not check a-zA-z because of unicode chars and i don't know regex rules. when remove [a-zA-z] then get error

Comment: '(?!('.$exceptions.')((\W+)|$)).+/?$' ??

Comment: Thanks Mark you're Legend

Answer (score 1):

Try adding something to match everything else, instead of your a-zA-Z rule.

```
'(?!('.$exceptions.')(.*))'
```

EDIT:

After reading your comment below. Maybe a better solution is to use the one proposed for this question: [wordpress: how to check if the slug contains a specific word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297991/wordpress-how-to-check-if-the-slug-contains-a-specific-word)

You can then check using something like this:

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$isException = strpos($url, 'word1');

if ($isException !== false)
{
    //url contains word in exceptions!
}
```

Comment: include a word with '-' or '_' character. the problem is i don't know regular expression

Comment: i need that for check slug in urls in cakephp router

Comment: Thanks Jonas alot for your attention, i changed the regex with Mark sent as comment and it works great

 Router::connect('/:language/:typeslug',
  array('controller' => 'nodetypes', 'action' => 'view'),
  array(
   'language'=>'[a-z]{3}',
   'typeslug' => '(?!('.$exceptions.')((\W+)|$)).+/?$',
   'pass'=>array('typeslug')
   )
  );

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, I think you're looking for this:

```
$exceptions = ["word1","word2","word3"];
       // or $exceptions = explode("|",$exceptions) to work with what you have already
if( in_array($string,$exceptions)) {
   // word is in exceptions
}
```

Comment: just want to do it with regular expressions, only remove a-zA-z rule, just want not checking the chars is in a-z or A-Z range because of unicode characters.